# Digital/Analog output generation with NI DAQMX c/c++

Tags: c++, c, nidaqmx, daq-mx

I'm struggling to find a way to generate a voltage output from my NI DAQMX, using C/C++.

I can't figure out how to use the NI device libraries, and I can't find any helpful examples online.

Does anyone have any examples or insight that they can share to solve this?

Comment: Did you check http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2835/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [this](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2835/en/), as already suggested.
Particularly,

```
DAQmxWriteAnalogF64(taskHandle, 1000, 0, 10.0, DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel, data, &written, NULL);
```

should be what you are looking for. Also, have a look at the reported examples "GenVoltageUpdate" and "WriteDigChan" for implementation insight.